# Unit-test RxSwift observable in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, rx-swift

I'm quite new to RxSwift. I have a view controller that has a typeahead/autocomplete feature (i.e., user types in a UITextField and as soon as they enter at least 2 characters a network request is made to search for matching suggestions). The controller's `viewDidLoad` calls the following method to set up an Observable:

```
class TypeaheadResultsViewController: UIViewController {

var searchTextFieldObservable: Observable<String>!
@IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!
private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
var results: [TypeaheadResult]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //... unrelated setup stuff ...
    setupSearchTextObserver()
}

func setupSearchTextObserver() {
            searchTextFieldObservable =
                self.searchTextField
                    .rx
                    .text
                    .throttle(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                    .map { $0 ?? "" }

            searchTextFieldObservable
                .filter { $0.count >= 2 }
                .flatMapLatest { searchTerm in self.search(for: searchTerm) }
                .subscribe(
                    onNext: { [weak self] searchResults in
                        self?.resetResults(results: searchResults)
                    },
                    onError: { [weak self] error in
                        print(error)
                        self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    }
                )
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)

            // This is the part I want to test:        
            searchTextFieldObservable
                .filter { $0.count < 2 }
                .subscribe(
                    onNext: { [weak self] _ in
                        self?.results = nil
                    }
                )
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine, but I'm struggling to figure out how to *unit test* the behavior of `searchTextFieldObservable`. 
To keep it simple, I just want a unit test to verify that `results` is set to `nil` when `searchTextField` has fewer than 2 characters after a change event.
I have tried several different approaches. My test currently looks like this:

```
    class TypeaheadResultsViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {
        var ctrl: TypeaheadResultsViewController!

        override func setUp() {
            super.setUp()
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)
            ctrl = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TypeaheadResultsViewController") as! TypeaheadResultsViewController
        }

        override func tearDown() {
            ctrl = nil
            super.tearDown()
        }

        /// Verify that the searchTextObserver sets the results array
        /// to nil when there are less than two characters in the searchTextView
        func testManualChange() {
          // Given: The view is loaded (this triggers viewDidLoad)
          XCTAssertNotNil(ctrl.view)
          XCTAssertNotNil(ctrl.searchTextField)
          XCTAssertNotNil(ctrl.searchTextFieldObservable)

          // And: results is not empty
          ctrl.results = [ TypeaheadResult(value: "Something") ]

          let tfObservable = ctrl.searchTextField.rx.text.subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
          //ctrl.searchTextField.rx.text.onNext("e")
          ctrl.searchTextField.insertText("e")
          //ctrl.searchTextField.text = "e"
          do {
              guard let result =
                try tfObservable.toBlocking(timeout: 5.0).first() else { 
return }
            XCTAssertEqual(result, "e")  // passes
            XCTAssertNil(ctrl.results)  // fails
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Basically, I'm wondering how to manually/programmatically fire an event on `searchTextFieldObservable` (or, preferably, on the `searchTextField`) to trigger the code in the 2nd subscription marked "This is the part I want to test:".

Comment: Does your test succeed if you delete the `throttle` operator in `searchTextFieldObservable`?

Comment: @kiwisip - No - same result. It seems the event is never fired. That is, I set a break-point on the first line in the `onNext` handler, and it is never hit (except for when the view is first loaded).

Comment: You should use RxBlocking for testing this async task. The test is not written too well... You should see https://www.gitbook.com/book/orta/pragmatic-ios-testing/details for writing better tests.  

If you would debug this, you would see that the onNext somewhere inside is called asynchronously and can be still on go when the XCTAssert is already done.

Comment: I've updated the test code to show the _actual_ test code as it is now, rather than the pseudo-code

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to separate the logic from the effects. Once you do that, it will be easy to test your logic. In this case, the chain you want to test is:

```
self.searchTextField.rx.text
.throttle(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
.map { $0 ?? "" }
.filter { $0.count < 2 }
.subscribe(
    onNext: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.results = nil
    }
)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The effects are only the source and the sink (another place to look out for effects is in any `flatMap`s in the chain.) So lets separate them out:

(I put this in an extension because I know how much most people hate free functions)

```
extension ObservableConvertibleType where E == String? {
    func resetResults(scheduler: SchedulerType) -> Observable<Void> {
        return asObservable()
            .throttle(0.5, scheduler: scheduler)
            .map { $0 ?? "" }
            .filter { $0.count < 2 }
            .map { _ in }
    }
}
```

And the code in the view controller becomes:

```
self.searchTextField.rx.text
    .resetResults(scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(
        onNext: { [weak self] in
            self?.results = nil
        }
    )
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Now, let's think about what we actually need to test here. For my part, I don't feel the need to test `self?.results = nil` or `self.searchTextField.rx.text` so the View controller can be ignored for testing.

So it's just a matter of testing the operator... There's a great article that recently came out: https://www.raywenderlich.com/7408-testing-your-rxswift-code However, frankly I don't see anything that needs testing here. I can trust that `throttle`, `map` and `filter` work as designed because they were tested in the RxSwift library and the closures passed in are so basic that I don't see any point in testing them either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `self.ctrl.searchTextField.rx.text.onNext("e")` won't trigger `searchTextFieldObservable` `onNext` subscription.

The subscription is also not triggered if you set the text value directly like this `self.ctrl.searchTextField.text = "e"`.

The subscription will trigger (and your test should succeed) if you set the textField value like this: `self.ctrl.searchTextField.insertText("e")`.

I think the reason for this is that `UITextField.rx.text` observes methods from `UIKeyInput`.

Comment: I tried using `self.ctrl.searchTextField.insertText("e")` but that still doesn't seem to trigger the event.

Comment: And if you remove the `throttle` now?

Comment: Removing `throttle` doesn't fix it, unfortunately. I've updated my question with my _real_ test code as it is now...

Comment: What if you write something like `DispatchQueue.main.asynchAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: { XCTAssertNil(ctrl.results) })` .. does this fail?

Comment: The problem is that the event never fires. I think what I'm really trying to figure out is how to manually/programmatically trigger an event on the `searchTextField` or the derived `searchTextFieldObservable`. I'm digging around the source code for RxCocoa/RxSwift. (Note - the comments for RxCocoa's `ControlProperty` class say "Programatic value changes won't be reported."  https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/Traits/ControlProperty.swift )

Comment: `insertText` works for me so it is really weird.. try that in playgrounds and you'll see it works

Comment: Thanks, you're right, really weird... I took your suggestion and added the following chunk to my view controller, at the end of the code that sets up the observable:
 `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.5) {
   self.searchTextField.insertText("This is programmatically added")
  }`  
After 2.5 seconds, the text field shows the text "This is programmatically added." 
So now I have to figure out why it doesn't work from the test. I'm guessing it might have to do with the test using a different Scheduler, or a different thread (or both)... idk

Comment: Keep playing and experimenting with it and you'll find a solution soon. Sometimes it gets tricky. I think the problem is the asynchronicity. You can try Nimble framework that makes it easier to do asynchronous testing. https://github.com/Quick/Nimble#asynchronous-expectations

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep UIViewControllers far away from my unit tests. Therefore, I suggest moving this logic to a view model.

As your bounty explanation details, basically what you are trying to do is mock the textField's `text` property, so that it fires events when you want it to. I would suggest replacing it with a mock value altogether. If you make `textField.rx.text.bind(viewModel.query)` the responsibility of the view controller, then you can focus on the view model for the unit test and manually alter the query variable as needed.

```swift
class ViewModel {
   let query: Variable<String?> = Variable(nil)
   let results: Variable<[TypeaheadResult]> = Variable([])

   let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

   init() {
     query
       .asObservable()
       .flatMap { query in 
          return query.count >= 2 ? search(for: $0) : .just([])
       }
       .bind(results)
       .disposed(by: disposeBag)
   }

   func search(query: String) -> Observable<[TypeaheadResult]> {
     // ...
   }
}
```

The test case:

```swift
class TypeaheadResultsViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    func testManualChange() {
      let viewModel = ViewModel()
      viewModel.results.value = [/* .., .., .. */]

      // this triggers the subscription, but does not trigger the search
      viewModel.query.value = "1"

      // assert the results list is empty
      XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.results.value, [])
   }
}
```

If you also want to test the connection between the textField and the view model, UI tests are a much better fit.

Note that this example omits:

1. Dependency injection of the network layer in the view model.
2. The binding of the view controller's textField value to `query` (i.e., `textField.rx.text.asDriver().drive(viewModel.query)`).
3. The observing of the results variable by the view controller (i.e., `viewModel.results.asObservable.subscribe(/* ... */)`).

<sub>There might be some typos in here, did not run it past the compiler.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the underlying implementation for `rx.text`, you'll see it relies on [`controlPropertyWithDefaultEvents`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/745c290e0235478d6294e76c4a28f280dc29a14b/RxCocoa/iOS/UITextField%2BRx.swift#L21) which [fires the following `UIControl` events: `.allEditingEvents` and `.valueChanged`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/745c290e0235478d6294e76c4a28f280dc29a14b/RxCocoa/iOS/UIControl%2BRx.swift#L73).

Simply setting the text, it won't fire any events, so your observable is not triggered. You have to send an action explicitly:

```swift
textField.text = "Something"
textField.sendActions(for: .valueChanged) // or .allEditingEvents
```

If you are testing within a framework, `sendActions` won't work because the framework is missing the `UIApplication`. You can do this instead

```swift
extension UIControl {
    func simulate(event: UIControl.Event) {
        allTargets.forEach { target in
            actions(forTarget: target, forControlEvent: event)?.forEach {
                (target as NSObject).perform(Selector($0))
            }
        }
    }
}

...

textField.text = "Something"
textField.simulate(event: .valueChanged) // or .allEditingEvents
```